# don't work RGB in openni_kinect

Tags: ros, openni-kinect, asus-xtion-pro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I have UBUNTU 11.10 electric
Please help
I installed the openni package:
**sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect
cd /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect
rosmake**
I disconnect the rgb cameras and hooked XTION
I launched:
**roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch**

After
**rosrun image_view disparity_view image:=/camera/depth/disparity**
and see that it work.

But when I started
**rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color**
I see only grey window!!!
It don't work!!!

I disconnect the rgb cameras
What's the problem? Help please. I had already tried everything .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191321/don%27t-work-rgb-in-openni_kinect/) by [niki](https://answers.ros.org/users/19694/niki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're using a deprecated ROS version (electric) on a version of ubuntu that is no longer supported (11.10) with a camera package that isn't released anymore (openni_kinect) and a camera whose chipset maker got bought by apple and so will likely stop getting sold at some point (xtion).

If you switch to ROS indigo on ubuntu 14.04 and use openni2_camera to read from the camera, you'll have a much better chance of finding people who know how to answer your questions.

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2014-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niki](https://answers.ros.org/users/19694/niki/) on 2014-08-27**:
Thanks.

I have a robot QBO and his OpenQbo Distro is the Linux distro based only on Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) ROS electric.

What should I do in this situation?